# Disallow edits to answers that only golf code further

Tags: discussion, editing

[This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57610/20666) had 2 suggested edits that *only* golf the code further, and the edits were both approved. I personally disagree with edits that only golf the code further. Here's why:

- It shouldn't be up to the reviewer to make sure a code edit works. That should be the job of the answerer. If an edit is accepted when it actually does not work, the answer may get unfair downvotes.
- Usually golfing suggestions from comments come in the form of `replace <a few characters of  the code> with <shorter replacement>` which might be easier to understand than the entire code being replaced.
- The answerer may not want the edit to be in their answer or may want to change the edit before incorporating it into their answer. Ultimately it's up to the answerer whether they want to use someone's changes; they should not be forced to do so by an accepted edit.

I think the policy on PPCG should be changed to **reject all** edits that only shorten the code, and to ask people to comment the changes instead.

Comment: Yes, that is already the recommended policy, but unfortunately not every reviewer knows about it. I've informed one of the reviewers now. Also note that the first edit was approved by the author of the answer.

Comment: Where can this policy be found? All I can find are questions like this one, nothing I turn up in the Help Center or Tour Page reveals this policy.